# How to read the width and the height of a flash file in C# or JS?

Tags: c#, javascript

What will i do to read the width and the height of a flash file (*.swf) in C# or JS?

I tried a solution in CodeProject.com but return value of height is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use [this one](http://jayakrishnagudla.blogspot.gr/2009/12/how-to-get-width-and-height-of-swf-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ["SwfDotNet"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/)

Comment: Thank akash! I read the SwfDotNet Documentation but i didn't see a clear solution to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `getComputedStyle`?
Here is a cross browser implementation coming [from here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade4.shtml)

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop){
 if (el.currentStyle) //IE
  return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
 else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //others
  return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
 else //try and get inline style
  return el.style[cssprop]
}

getStyle(elm, 'height')
```

It returns the value of any css property of an element.

If that doesn't work you could try to embed your flash file in a DIV and measure it instead of the swf object.

### EDIT:

Here is an example that work on webkit, Opera.

```
<div id="container" style="float:left">
    <embed 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      src="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/watch_as3-vfl178359.swf">
</div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('container'),
        css = window.getComputedStyle(div, null);
    alert( css.height +' - '+ css.width );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank Mic for your help.

I did as follows your advice but no success. On Firefox the value of height is incorrect and On IE is 'auto'.

Comment: strange... look at the example I added. My Firefox doesn't want to start since the last update and I don't have an IE to test right now...

Comment: Hi mic, I think the Javascript solution is impossible because the Macromedia Flash Player work directly with the flash object instead of the Browser Engine.

I'm looking the C# solution.